# Why my javascript not work? When I change the innterHtml of an element, it didn't work

Tags: javascript, html

## Why my javascript not work? When I change the innterHtml of an element, it didn't work?

### here is my code:

#### html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>403 没有权限！</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body {
          user-select: none;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      .container { margin: 50px auto 40px auto; width: 600px; text-align: center; }

      a { color: #4183c4; text-decoration: none; }
      h1 { width: 800px; position:relative; left: -100px; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 60px; font-size: 160px; font-weight: 100; margin: 0px 0 50px 0; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; }
      p,m { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); margin: 20px 0; line-height: 1.6; }
      #suggestions {
        margin-top: 35px;
        color: #ccc;
      }
      #suggestions a {
        color: #666666;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0 10px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
    
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <h1><strong>403</strong></h1>
      <p><strong>Request denied</strong></p>
      <p><strong>请求被拒绝</strong></p>

      <p>
        If the file you are accessing is yours, please check your login information.
      </p>
      <m>You are now login as: </m><f id="ll"></f>

    </div>

    <script src="get.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

#### js

```js
var datac
var user

function get(){
    user = localStorage.getItem(datac)
    if(user != null){
        document.getElementById("ll").innerHtml = user
        console.log(user)
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('ll').innerHtml = 'Please Login.'
    }
}

function checklogin(){
    $.getJSON('https://text-edit-api-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/.json', function ( data ){
    datac = data['data']['password']['localstorge']['code']
    get()
})}

checklogin()
```

There is no any errors in console!
but if I get `document.getElementById('ll').innterHtml` I saw the change, but there is no changes in html!

This page is the 404 page of github page, I changed some codes.

I change innter to inner

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgE9D.png)

I use vscode
And chrome

Comment: document.getElementById('ll').innterHtml should be document.getElementById('ll').innerHTML (this is regarded as typo)

Comment: which code editor are you using ?

Comment: use vs code or sublime and press `ctrl + space` so you will be prompt with right syntax which can save you from sytax errors

Comment: and in your code you have a typo `innerHTML` and `innerText` this two are valid syntax

Answer (score 1):

It is weird you don't have errors in console. Be carfeully about the uppercase letters, the correct attribute is **innerHTML** instead of innerHtml

Comment: Not weird at all: `.innterHtml` is a user-created property, and thus does not raise an error, even though it does not achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax problem. Put `innerHTML` instead of `innterHtml`

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: I change it, it still didn't work...

Comment: You should check the javascript console and network. Maybe your $.getJSON got an error and the callback is not executed.
Also put more console.log() inside your function to check where your codes go as well.

Comment: **There is No ANY errors in the Console**

Comment: Then check the network and see the response status and content. Also do a `console.log(user)` after getting the localstorage, tell me what you see

Comment: @user16376844 It should be `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`.

Comment: My bad, I also typed it too quick. You got the MDN doc, you got the idea.